# svn-dump-reloc use in windows command prompt

Tags: svn

I want to use "svn-dump-reloc" command for restructure in SVNDUMP.
I can get the script from below location,
http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc

I want to know, how to deploy this script to use this command

OR

Please let me know, any other source to use this command "svn-dump-reloc" on windows environment.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the resolution as below:

Current folder structure is as below:

Project
        -- branches
        -- tags
        -- trunk
        -- SubProject1 > (files and folder)
        -- SubProject2 > (folder1, folder2)
        -- ReleaseNotes

Restructure as below like standard SVN layout:

Project
       -- branches
       -- tags
       -- trunk
(Move to trunk) SubProject1 > (files and folder)
(Move to trunk) SubProject2 > (folder1, folder2)
(Move to trunk) ReleaseNotes

Follow the steps as below:

1. Download "SVN-DumpReloc-0.02" 
   Installed "ActivePerl 5.16.1 Build 1601" MSI
2. In GIT MingW editor, 
   execute command "cd c:/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02"
   execute command "perl Makefile.PL" result: "writing Make file for SVN::DumpReloc"

NOTE: After that, should have to execute "make install" command but it raises an error for try rule......etc.. and didn't work. So, its fine to skip to execute "make install"
(downloaded utility "GNUWin32" which allows to execute make command in windows)

3.

=>cat svn.dump | "c:/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc" SubProject1 trunk/SubProject1 > svn.fixed.dump

=>cat svn.fixed.dump | "c:/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc" SubProject2 trunk/SubProject2 > svn1.fixed.dump

=>cat svn1.fixed.dump | "c:/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc" ReleaseNotes trunk/SubProject2 > svn2.fixed.dump

iterate for each relocation.. Just make sure to give full path for "svn-dump-reloc".

4.
 now, dump file is updated for restructure the folders and you can verify by loading the dump into SVN

Thanks
Dhaval Soni