# history not preserve while move svn to GIT (for svn Move folders)

Tags: git-svn

I have an SVN project with a structure as specified below:
PROJECT > trunk, branches, tags, subproject1, subproject2, release notes

I have restructured the project through the SVN MOVE command so it looks like:
trunk, branches, Tags.  (moved the folders into trunk).

I'm able to see history preserved as I moved through SVN MOVE command.

Now, I have migrated the SVN repository to GIT through below command,

$ git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt file:///svnrepos/local-svn/PROJECT project.git

NOw, In the GIT repository, I am not able see the history for moved folders and it only shows me last "svn move" command history. I can see history for all other files which are not moved.

Please let me know your comments.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN Move will not be able to preserve the history while moving to GIT as it will consider as new directory entry commit in GIT.

there is require to use SVN-DUMP-RELOC  which will restrcutre the directory in SVN DUMP file instead of repository.

Please follow the steps mentioned in below link for windows machine:
[svn-dump-reloc use in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972693/svn-dump-reloc-use-in-windows-command-prompt)

Thanks